# Couldn't find disk developer image, Xcode Compatibility issue

Tags: xcode, compatibility

I ran into this problem when iOS 10 was released. They are updating their device definitions so fast, that our small dev team can't match their speed. In result we need to develop on previous versions. But now our app crashes on 10.1 and we cannot debug. We need to wait for whole download to happen. Is it so hard to manage dev disk image to a place ? do they maintain disk image? or any other solution to the problem.

Comment: There can be several reasons for crashing on iOS 10. E.g. If you accessed photo gallery, camera, contacts in previous versions, they will crash on iOS 10 if you don't add [usage strings](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) to your plist. Also If you used ABPeoplePicker for selecting contacts, it will crash unless you switch to CNPeoplePicker. Etc

Comment: Yes that is true but it can be debugged only when we can see logs, right ?

Comment: if you are using xcode 8.0 and ios 10.1 than your app will not run in ios 10.1. You have to update xcode to 8.1 latest version. But you can download xip of xcode to run two xcode simultaneously and run in your device. @nikka

Comment: Can be debugged on 7.3 if disk developer image is copied @kar